# Is it ok to use drydex joint compound for nail pop fixes?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

I am a DIY guy that has a handful of nail pops to resolve in my home. I’m intimidated by the drywall mud that requires mixing, and I’m not trying to be a drywallologist over here I’m just trying to fix my house up in few places. I’ve gravitated to using the drydex joint compound that goes on pink and dries white for various patching jobs that require fibatape throughout my house. I’ve gotten a good feel on how to use it and sand it down to a finish I’m happy with.

All YouTube videos show how to resolve nail pops and they pull out the compound that you have to mix. Is it ok for me to substitute the drydex pink to white joint compound for these nail pop jobs?

I get that a drywall repair expert would laugh at me but I’m just trying to make it work with my skill set. So is this method ok?

Comment: No it's perfectly fine and in fact it's actually the better product for your use case. Drydex doesn't need priming and shrinks much less.

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Comment: Yeah, technically you can make it work, but for things big enough to require tape (ie, not your nail pops), you could use premixed all purpose joint compound. It’s easier to sand than the setting (powdered) compounds, but it does shrink more and take a while to dry.

Comment: This is perfectly fine, mixing a tiny batch of dry compound actually would be a waste of that is all the work your doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DryDEx is made for smaller jobs, like what you are doing.

The pink, color changing formula is good for "freshman DIYers" as it lets you know when it is dry.  It also is formulated to eliminate pinpoint holes. That's an issue many DIYers are confused with.

You are using the right product. Spackle on.

Comment: I've used the pink-to-white stuff for nail pops, minor hole filling when taking pictures & shelves down before selling the house, etc. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The mixed dry compound is cheaper for large jobs and allows the user to customize large batches for their application - more or less water, additives, etc.  The pre-mixed stuff is basically the same thing in a smaller, more expensive batch made for general purpose applicatons.  It's entirely appropriate for small jobs.

You should be just fillng the shallow holes above the two nails and two new screws. There shouldn't be much sanding much at all. Fill those holes, let it dry and it will slightly shrink/cup, then top it off flush with the wall.  The surrounding drywall shouldn't have any compound on it, clean it off before it dries.